# Eclipse + Pydev + pylint + pep8 - can't get the editor to ignore E501 errors

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev, pylint, autopep8

I'd like to be able to either increase the max linelength or tell the code formatting checkers to ignore E501. Previous solutions are very old, but more importantly, do not work for me. I just installed eclipse:

```
Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112
Code formatter settings:
autopep8
--ignore=E501 --max-line-length=110
Pydev
python 3.10
using pylint
```

Also, I'm running in a virtual python environment

Please let me know if other info is needed.
I can't seem to get autopep8 (or pylint if that is possible) to take any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I conclude there is no way to suppress or modify pep8 telling you that your linelength is longer than 80 characters as I've had zero solutions recommended. I also conclude that pep8 is not being actively worked on.